# Where can I store the amount of android in-game currency?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, currency, backend

My game app offers in game currency to buy virtual goods. Google Wallet keeps only track of my currency purchases.
If I save the bought goods on the phone, they get lost on reinstall. Furthermore you can't access the goods from other user devices. Is this the standard way?

I suppose a backend server is a good alternative for this kind of data.
If yes: Is a backend service like App Engine to oversized for my purpose?

Update: There is also the Android Backup Service. With this service you can save the preferences in the cloud and they would be restored after reinstall.

Comment: The recently launched Google Cloud Save springs to mind https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need storage that is cloud-based. Datastore may solve that issue for you. With Datastore you keep the data associated to each user in it and is retrieve from your application when needed.

But as Gwyn pointed out, Google Cloud Save is your best choice. It is similar in functionality (it's built upon Datastore) but more straightforward for you to use.